# Make water wash over an object

Tags: modeling

I managed to get an object (a submarine in this case) float on the ocean using the shrinkwrap modifier, which works really well. Now, the surfaced submarine is floating, but when the waves wash over parts of the deck, it looks very unrealistic because the water does not disperse and stick to the surface of the deck. How can I get this effect ? To make it look like the water is actuallly washing over the deck, with splashes if possible ?

Comment: Please show us some screenshots of your result

Comment: with Fluid simulation maybe?

Comment: I think dynamic paint set to waves should do the trick. There are plenty of dynamic paint tutorials out there which can explain dynamic paint to you much better than anyone through text on this site can. I also recommend reading blender manual on this topic.                  A quick demo of dynamic paint: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XOSfuZ178-Z-qX7qthNewzIjddVSYO1C/view?usp=sharing